# Reagent: How to get new props from component-will-receive-props?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

So signature for `component-will-receive-props` is such:

https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/src/reagent/core.cljs#L114

`:component-will-receive-props (fn [this new-argv])`

But `new-args` seems like it's function or js object. I was expecting it to be map of props. How do I get map of props from `new-argv`? I can get old props from `this` by `(reagent/props this)`, but it's old props, not newly received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I finally found out it's `reagent.impl.util/extract-props`. 
So `(reagent.impl.util/extract-props new-argv)` will return new props.

https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/v0.5.1-rc3/src/reagent/impl/util.cljs#L11

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to do this is through the props function. [An example here](http://nils-blum-oeste.net/clojurescripts-reagent-using-props-in-lifecycle-hooks/) shows this.

```
;; assuming you have reagent required :as reagent

(reagent/create-class
  {
  ...

  :should-component-update
  (fn [this]
    (println "next-props" (reagent/props this))
  ...
  })
```

Comment: This returns the current props and not the new props, which is what the OP was looking for.